# Describe null space and range of a linear transformation; Apostol

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Question from Apostol's Calculus 2 book - Chapter 2

Let $V$ be the linear space of all real functions continuous o $[a,b]$ and let $T$ be a transformation $T: V \to V$. If $f \in V, g= T(f)$ means that $$ g(x)= \int_a^b f(t)\sin(x-t)dt \space$$ For $a \le x \le b$. Describe the null space and range of $T$.

Comment: It may be helpful to note that we can rewrite the integral (via a u-substitution) as 
$$
g(x) = \int_{x - b}^{x - a} f(x - t)\sin(t)\,dt
$$

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't know the Stone-Weierstrass theorem, but I thought the following: $$\int_a^b f(t)\sin(x-t)dt \space = \int_a^b f(t)[\sin(x)\cos(t) -\sin(t)\cos(x)] dt =$$ $$ \sin(x)\int_a^b f(t)\cos(t)dt - \cos(x)\int_a^b f(t)\sin(t)dt $$ Now suppose that $a \neq b$ (although the problem doesn't let that clear, it's reasonable, otherwise $g$ would be ever zero), then the rank is at most 2. Indeed, $g(x)= A\sin(x) +B\cos(x)$, with A e B reals. A possible basis would be $cos(x)$ and $sin(x)$. But, it's necessary prove that A and B assume values such that the basis has more than one element.

Thus, the nullity is infinity according to the nullity plus rank theorem, which 
invalidate that $f=0$ is only option of continuous function to the nullspace. The answer of the book is rank=2 and nullity is infinity.

It's incomplete. It lacks describe the range and the null space.

Comment: Nice answer! I just think you should answer so that you are describing the range and nullspace as the question asks for - not the rank and the nullity.

Comment: Your answer is better than mine was, well done

Comment: My answer is incomplete. The answer should describe the  nullspace and the range.